# Saving an array to MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a schema for my MongoDb collection.

```
   module.exports = (mongoose, Schema) => {
      let eventSchema = new Schema({
        name: String
        values: ???
      });
    
      return mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
    };
```

I receive a json like this one:

```
{"1965": 10000000, "1966": 20000000, "1967": 300000}
```

I want this array to be in the "values" field of the eventSchema. How do I save it to my db?
Years vary,  and the number of objects in array is always different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const payload = { name : "test" , values : {"1965": 10000000, "1966": 20000000, "1967": 300000}
 }

const  event = new Event(payload)

event.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  // saved!
});
```

and make sure your schema is :

```
let eventSchema = new Schema({
        name: String
        values: Object
      });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking about subdocuments and missed the easier solution!